# How to set the Azure WebApp Environment variables/Configuration values from Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-core-3.1, azure-webapps

I have a .Net Core 3.1 WebAPI with the following configurations in the appsettings.json file

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "demo@gmail.onmicrosoft.com", //Domain name configured in Azure: null,
    "TenantId": "xxxxx", // Tenant Id configured in Azure
    "ClientId": "xxxx", //  Client Id configured in Azure
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxxx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I have created an Azure WebApp and added the above settings

[image]

and deployed the application using zip package, it works as expected.

However, I am asked to store the credentials in the Azure Key vault and use it instead of directly storing it at the WebApp level.

What should I do so that WebAPP configuration would pull the configuration values from the Azure Key Vault and have it ready for the application to use?

Comment: you can use key vault reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli